# Select diagonals that pass from a point in 2d array

Tags: c#, matrix, windows-runtime, diagonal

I have grid where items are placed in rows and columns, but this is not what we have to care about since each element binds `X` and `Y` properties so we just have to go match the element with right coordinates in a `List`.

When the user clicks a cell in the grid, all the other cells that shape the teo diagonals AND cross the selected cell must change their color.

[image: grid]

Actually I managed to write some code that only highlights the first diagonal, but no the reverse one. (10x10 squared grid)

```
    var t = // selected cell that contains X,Y coordinates

    var newX = (t.Y > t.X) ? 0 : t.X - t.Y;
    var newY = (t.Y > t.X) ? t.Y - t.X : 0;
    var maxOffset = ((newX > newY) ? newX : newY);

    for (int b = 0; b + maxOffset < GRID_SIZE; b++)
    {
        // this is selected cell, just skip it
        if ((newX + b) == t.X && (newY + b) == t.Y) continue;

        // select the cell to highlight
        var projection = this.items.Where((i) => (i.X == (newX + b) && i.Y == (newY + b))).First();

    }
```

But I'm stuck here.

- It doesn't work on rectangular matrix
- It doesn't highlight reverse diagonal

I'd like to highlight the reverse diagonal passing from selected cell and possibly using the same vars and loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your cells were stored in an array, looping would be a good approach - but since you already have objects that contain the X and Y coordinates for every cell, you can just do this:

```
var t = // selected cell that contains X,Y coordinates
var diagonals = cells.Where(n => Math.Abs(t.X - n.X) == Math.Abs(t.Y - n.Y));
```

This finds every cell where the X distance from the selected cell equals the Y distance from that cell.

Comment: That's frustrating! I wrote down on a piece of paper tons of scheme and you came out with a one-line solution.